# How to sample inhomogeneous Poisson processes in Python faster than this?

Tags: python, random, poisson

I'm sampling a Poisson process at a millisecond time scale where the rate is not fixed. I discretise the sampling process by checking in each interval of size delta whether there is an event there or not based on the average rate in that interval. Since I'm using Python it's running a bit slower than I would hope it to be. The code I'm currently using is the following:

```
import numpy
def generate_times(rate_function,max_t,delta):
    times = []
    for t in numpy.arange(delta,max_t,delta):
        avg_rate = (rate_function(t)+rate_function(t+delta))/2.0
        if numpy.random.binomial(1,1-math.exp(-avg_rate*delta/1000.0))>0:
            times.extend([t])
    return times
```

The rate function can be arbitrary, I'm not looking for a closed form solution given a rate function.

If you want some parameters to play with you can try:

```
max_t = 1000.0
delta = 0.1
high_rate = 100.0
low_rate = 0.0
phase_length = 25.0
rate_function = (lambda x: low_rate + (high_rate-low_rate)*0.5*(1+math.sin(2*math.pi*x/phase_length)))
```

Comment: Are you asking how to _optimize_ ```generate_times```? Can it return an ndarray or must it be a list?

Comment: It does not need to be fully optimised, any factor greater than 5 in the runtime would make a huge difference. And the output must be a list (you can convert an ndarray into a list in the end if that's faster... :P).

Comment: ```generate_times``` seems incomplete, it never adds anything to ```tunes```

Comment: Thanks, fixed it now.

Comment: Have you looked at other SO answers regarding _vectorizing_ calcs on ndarrays?

Comment: If the rate is not constant why do you call it a Poisson process? I thought that a constant arrival rate was part of the *definition* of a Poisson process.

Comment: @JohnColeman https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inhomogeneous_Poisson_process

Comment: @musically_ut I see. It is a generalization of the classic Poisson process. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a version which runs about 75x faster and implements the same function:

```
def generate_times_opt(rate_function,max_t,delta):
    t = numpy.arange(delta,max_t, delta)
    avg_rate = (rate_function(t) + rate_function(t + delta)) / 2.0
    avg_prob = 1 - numpy.exp(-avg_rate * delta / 1000.0)
    rand_throws = numpy.random.uniform(size=t.shape[0])

    return t[avg_prob >= rand_throws].tolist()
```

Output:

```
11:59:07 [70]: %timeit generate_times(rate_function, max_t, delta)
10 loops, best of 3: 75 ms per loop

11:59:23 [71]: %timeit generate_times_opt(rate_function, max_t, delta)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.15 ms per loop
```

---

**Sidenote:** This is not the best way to simulate an Inhomogenous Poisson Process, though. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inhomogeneous_Poisson_process):

> An inhomogeneous Poisson process with intensity function λ(t) can be simulated by rejection sampling from a homogeneous Poisson process with fixed rate λ: choose a sufficiently large λ so that λ(t) = λ p(t) and simulate a Poisson process with rate parameter λ. Accept an event from the Poisson simulation at time t with probability p(t).

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot, the alternative from the wikipedia page also makes a lot of sense. It is weak in respect to having one maximum for the rate function and other values close to 0.